# Is there a way to import just an album from iPhone to Apple Photos?

Tags: photos

I have selected a few photos on my iPhone and placed them into a new album.

I want to import that album **only**, but in Photos it doesn't look like there is a way to import just a single album. From what I can tell there is no option to do *any* filtering, not even favourites, or videos, etc.

I can either import everything, or manually select the photos I want.

Am I missing something?